# Factor order in R

Tags: r

I have a list of trips that each one contains a sequence of visited places.

I am trying to group these trips by sequence, keeping the order as below

```
Trip 101: SA
Trip 102: MA->SA->MA

T   s   p   d
101 1   SA  2016/02/04
102 1   MA  2016/02/04
102 2   SA  2016/02/04
102 3   MA  2016/02/04
```

with this code I get:

```
101: SA
102: MA->MA->SA - Wrong

dframe <- places %>%
 arrange(p) %>%
 select(-s) %>%
 unique() %>%
 group_by(t, d) %>%
 summarise(seqTrip=paste(p,collapse="->")) %>%
 ungroup()
```

I added the factor ordered=False, but doesn't work any suggestion?

Comment: Are you just trying to do `aggregate(p ~ t + d, places, paste, collapse = "->")`?

Comment: Hi! Ive tried but not working. I am using P as factor and it gets sorted alphabetically

Comment: I managed to keep the order by removing the line arrange(P).